# Which set operation generates the $\mathbb{Z}_4$ group?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

The Klein four-group is the group generated by the symmetric difference as the binary operation on the subsets of a power set of a set with two elements $\{a,b\}$, that means over its superset with four elements: $\{\{\},\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. $\mathbb Z_4$ is the group generated for which set operation??? I could not find it, any try was meaningless. The two tables:

[image]

Comment: Must there be one?

Comment: "Must there be one? "  <----- If set theory is the foundation of mathematics, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that we can use set theory to ground the foundation of mathematics, but that doesn't mean that every mathematical object can be expressed simply in terms of set operations. For example, we can use axiomatic set theory to show that $1+1 = 2$, but when Whitehead and Russel tried to give a super rigorous set theoretic undergirding to mathematics it took them 379 pages to show that that formula holds(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica page count is roughly accurate, depends on the edition). So it set theory the foundation of mathematics? Yes, it is at least *a* foundation for mathematics, but that doesn't mean that all ideas in mathematics can be simply expressed in terms of foundational principles.

Comment: But what about 2+2? Can its correct answer be deductively proven? Using set theory, was 1+1=2 proven (after being shown without proof) in 379 pages via induction, deduction, or a combination? What formula holds?

Comment: @victamon from my understanding, I don't think Ruseel and Whitehead really ever recovered from Gödel's work on the subject, so I don't think they got to that one :)

Comment: Whitehead and Russell's _Principia Mathematica_ is *not* based on set theory. It is based on Russell's Theory of Types.